# Why *must* delete[] and delete be different?

Tags: c++, memory-management, language-design, delete-operator

I'm well aware that in C++, what `delete[]` is to `new[]`, `delete` is to `new`. This is not about C++ syntax. I am wondering about the **reasons** `delete[]` was defined as something distinct from the plain `delete`. What are the implementation reasons for this?

Consider what happens with this code:

```
MyClass *object = new MyClass;
delete object;
```

When `delete` is encountered the memory manager has to lookup the object pointer value in its allocation structure, whatever it is, and mark the corresponding `sizeof(MyClass)` chunk of memory as free.

Now consider what happens with this code:

```
MyClass *array = new MyClass[ num_objects ];
delete [] array;
```

When `delete` is encountered the memory manager has to lookup the array pointer value in its allocation structure, whatever it is, **find `num_objects` value from that structure** , and mark the corresponding `num_objects*sizeof(MyClass)` chunk of memory as free.

Apart from `num_objects` being assumed 1 in the single object case and looked up in the internal data structure in the array case I don't see the difference. So why `delete` and `delete[]` couldn't have been spelled identically?

In other words, what's wrong with

```
MyClass *object = new MyClass;
```

being implemented as

```
MyClass *object = new MyClass[1];
```

so that C++ syntax wouldn't have to make distinction between `delete` and `delete[]` ?

Comment: Because it's not just about releasing memory, it's also about calling the proper destructor the right amount of times.

Comment: `new` is thus somewhat cheaper than `new[]` because it doesn't have to store the number of times it must call destructors.

Comment: Actually for some compilers the implementation *is* the same, that's why people got away with writing `delete array;` and then got bitten when they switched compilers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In principle, these could be implemented in the same way. However, there's a cost to storing the number of elements somewhere, iterating over those elements, and calling the destructor on each (both in terms of time and in terms of space.)

One of the core philosophies of C++ is "don't pay for what you don't use." Since there is an extra cost associated with the array-based allocation and deallocation routines that programmers might not want to pay for, the language explicitly makes the two operations separate.

Comment: If you know the size of the allocated memory block, the number of objects is simply `block_size / sizeof(MyClass)`.  However, for technical reasons, `malloc` (and `new`) can allocate a larger block than you asked for, so this is why `new []` may still need to explicitly store the number of objects.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, the functionality of `new/delete` is different from that of `new[]/delete[]`. The former can be used to perform polymorphic allocation and polymorphic deletion. The latter does not support polymorphism at all. Arrays in C++ are not polymorphic, only individual objects are. It is probably possible to forcefully converge these two functionalities into one, in order to allow polymorphic deletion of single objects and still keep polymorphic deletion of arrays illegal, but it won't look pretty.

Secondly, as you probably know, a typical implementation of `new[]` will store the exact number of objects in the allocated array to be used later by `delete[]` to call the proper number of destructors. However, most modern implementations actually go through the trouble of *not* storing the array size when the allocated type has trivial destructor.

Why do they do that? They do that to save memory, i.e. to avoid storing the size when it can be avoided. Note that they go through all that trouble even in situations where the relative memory loss is generally small (one `size_t` field compared to an *array* of objects).

So, apparently this kind of memory saving technique is considered to be worth the effort.

Under such circumstances it is obvious that it should be even more worth it in situations when the array size is known to be exactly 1, i.e. from this point of view implementing `new T` through `new T[1]` would be exceedingly wasteful.